# Schedule notification based on incremental random time interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification

How to schedule the notification based on the incremental time span

**10 min, 10 hours, 20 hours, 1 day, 5 days, 1 week, 1 month, 5 month, 1 year, 5 years, 10 years.**

```
Notification Message:
for 10 min
You have completed Successfully 10 min
for 10 hours
You have completed Successfully 10 hours
```

Comment: just schedule the first notification, then when it fires schedule the next notification and so on.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve, given question doesn't actually tell, a proper use case. Give more detail so better solutions can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

From the little information provided, I would proceed like the following :

1. Look at NSUserDefaults to see what was the previous iteration
2. Define a start time based on that previous iteration (if any)
3. Schedule a local notification using the [Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app) provided in the iOS SDK.
4. Save that same date/time in the `NSUserDefaults`.
5. Once we reach that time, the notification will be sent (by iOS), and we can execute code to repeat this sequence.